# Kubernetes yaml with privileged flag

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm  trying to create `K8` yaml file that match to:

```
docker run --privileged
```

What I'm  trying in my `K8` yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  privileged: true
....
```

But when I'm trying to run `kubectl apply -f my.yaml` I got the following error:

> error: error validating "my.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): 
>   unknown field "privileged" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate
>   =false

How can I create yaml deployment file with `privileged` flag?

Answer (score 12):

`privileged: true` needs to be in `securityContext` in the spec section of the pod template.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  pause
          image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
```